# How can I detect other beacons Android -

Tags: android, altbeacon

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    try {                        
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6") // UUID for beacon
                .setId2("1") // Major for beacon
                .setId3("5") // Minor for beacon
                .setManufacturer(0x004C) // Radius Networks.0x0118  Change this for other beacon layouts//0x004C for iPhone
                .setTxPower(-56) // Power in dB
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
                .build();
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
        BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("tag", "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.i("tag", "Advertisement start succeeded.");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception o)
    {
    }
}
```

I am using [AltBeacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconTransmitter.java) to turn my phone to a beacon.I am getting in my adb logcat avdertisment start succeeded. However I want to detect other phones now that are acting as a beacon, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting beacons with the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) is simple.  See the Ranging Sample Code section on this page:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

As the example code linked above show, you will get a callback approximately once per second with a list of all beacons visible over that time in a method that looks like this:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
      // The beacons collection contains all beacons detected in the past second
}
```